# error in marketing cloud- connector

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

i am getting marketing cloud connector error while i am trying to connect salesforce marketing cloud user from the marketing cloud. 
error displays following messege 
**(An exception occurred while saving the integration.)**

I am trying to integrate the salesforce account from 
marketing cloud.
Admin >> Salesforce Integration >> Connect Account. after entering the credentials for the salesforce org it displays the following error.

Comment: The best way to go is to contact the support..

Answer (score 2):

We generally see these exceptions occur trying to connect the integration when the Salesforce System User has not be configured properly on the SF CRM side for the authentication. Follow the steps in the below doc to ensure that the proper permissions are assigned to the System User, as well as Permission Sets (eg. Marketing Cloud for AppExchange User and Marketing Cloud for AppExchange Admin user permissions, Marketing Cloud Connected App permission set).

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_set_up_authentication.htm&type=5

Once you can confirm that the above was completed, then you should be able to complete the connection.